# Divide And Conquer Bubble Sort Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, divide-and-conquer

This semester we learned about **Divide and Conquer** in which the problem is divided into subproblems and then solved just like in Merge Sort or Quick Sort.
Though I am not posting this question to get my assignment solved by you people , Our professor gave us an assignment to implement Bubble Sort as a divide and conquer algorithm , Now I'm sitting on my laptop scratching my head for days on how Bubble Sort can be divide and conquer algorithm.
If I try to implement **Bubble Sort** as divide and conquer the array must be divided , when I divide the array into its last element and then merge it back to its sorted form , The algorithm just becomes Merge Sort.
If I implement it by recursively calling bubbleSort(array,size-1) , the algorithm becomes **Reduce and Conquer**.
My question is "**How can bubble sort be implemented as Divide and Conquer Algorithm ?**"

Comment: a quick google turns up https://www.cs.iusb.edu/~danav/teach/b424/b424_15_bubblesort.html https://www.cpp.edu/~gsyoung/CS370/14Sp/parallel_sorting_kla%20Danny.pdf

Comment: imo, you are correct. Merge sort is but the divide and conquer approach over bubble sort(which by itself is an iterative algo). Perhaps your Prof played a trick question on you.

Comment: Given the Bubble Sort Algorithm and its complexity as O(n2), convert it into Divide & Conquer Algorithm and calculate its time complexity.

Comment: Suppose you just wrote a regular bubble sort algorithm, and then used that in place of the merge helper in merge sort.

Comment: I wanna be sure about this !

Comment: @KennyOstrom So in Merge sort two elements are checked and sorted to make a sorted sub array , this statement if written in DAC Bubble sort would make it Merge Sort because we would need to merge the sorted sub arrays to create the sorted array !

Comment: You wouldn't have to do any comparisons on the base case, because bubblesort will do that check anyway.

Comment: Wait , Trying to understand

Comment: Please write an answer , I would accept if it works !

Comment: But you'd have to think about the worst case of using bubblesort to merge two sorted sublists. Everything in the first sublist is bigger than everything in the second sublist. But the problem is only half as bad as the true worst case, in one sense.

Comment: No way. How do I know you already wrote your own bubblesort, or your own merge sort? :)

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do !

Comment: *when I divide the array into its last element and then merge it back to its sorted form , The algorithm just becomes Merge Sort* That's a fine observation. Why do you think there's a problem with your conclusion?

Comment: I'm afraid that there might be another way to "do it" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you write a `bubblesort` function that lets you sort part of an array:

```
bubblesort(arr, start, end)
{
    // sorts the items from arr[start] to arr[end]
}
```

So if you had the array `[1,7,4,9,6,3,2,5]` and called `bubblesort(arr, 0, 3)`, the resulting array would be `[1,4,7,9,6,3,2,5]`.

Now imagine what would happen if you made these calls:

```
bubblesort(arr, 0, 1);
bubblesort(arr, 2, 3);
bubblesort(arr, 4, 5);
bubblesort(arr, 6, 7);
```

Then

```
bubblesort(arr, 1, 3);
bubblesort(arr, 4, 7);
```

And, finally:

```
bubblesort(arr, 0, 7);
```

It's the same call pattern as merge sort, but it's definitely not merge sort.

Comment: but still does not work , can you please guide me on what's wrong

Comment: @WaqasTahir The first problem is that your `bubbleSort` method doesn't work. Fix that first. Then, re-think what your `mergeSort` is doing. Give it some thought, single-step your code in the debugger. If you still have trouble, post a new question that explains what you're trying to do, include your code, and describe the problem you're having.

Comment: What's the time complexity

Comment: @WaqasTahir Time complexity of this divide-and-conquer bubble sort? O(n^2).